# Store output of attached virtual interfaces for a particular bridge

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to store the interfaces output of `brctl show <bridge-name>`

For example the command below gives a tabular output with all the veths attaches in the last column:

```
brctl show lxcbr0
```

Is there a way to store these veths in a bash variable? The variable can be a string or a list/array.

Here is the output:
`lxcbr0     8000.fe2055f9d34c    no     veth2WDTUX
                                                        vethFEGPIX
                                                        vethGAMI9B
                                                        vethGQSYPY
                                                        vethKW3MUF
                                                        vethM7A3QN
                                                        vethNC26F7
                                                        vethNW6O6U
                                                        vethWPDU0U`

Comment: Can you show the output of the command?

Comment: @Will, I have added the output.

Comment: @HassaanPasha Please post the output as text in your question, and not as an image.